# Is there a way to tell HtmlUnit to grab all the dependancies

Tags: integration-testing, htmlunit

I'm using HtmlUnit for web testing and it is great. But I also want to test the download time for the total page including linked images, javascript and CSS pages as well as ensure the links are valid. Is there a way to tell HtmlUnit to grab all the dependancies for any given html page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of anything as part of HtmlUnit itself, but it's not hard to do yourself.

Pull out all the dependent links yourself — e.g. use `getByXPath()` to retrieve all the `<a>` tags — and iterate through them and have HtmlUnit pull each down individually.

Just be careful using this to determine download times:  unless you emulate how a "real" browser would retrieve things in parallel, you will not get an accurate measure.   A tool like [Xenu](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) would be a better tool for this job.